# Auto capitalise the character i

Tags: 8.0, keyboard

Does anyone know how to get a WP8 device to auto capitalise the character i? iOS performs this operation and it's really annoying me on my Lumia 820.

Comment: In what context are you trying to do this. Any particular app? Or is this globally failing. Is it failing any other capitalization? Also what language /country settings are set on the phone?

Comment: I'm using my phone with English keyboard and it does capitalize "i" character.

Comment: Hoping that you just want to capitalize i in 'I know what I want'.

Comment: Unverified myself, but this link suggests that it's only a problem for GB dictionary, and US works fine: http://r2.reddit.com/r/windowsphone/comments/1ko3k0/all_i_want_is_the_the_i_to_capitalise/

Answer (score 2):

Change to the English keyboard.

If you're unable to do so, go to **Settings** and add the keyboard.

You can have multiple keyboards at the same time and easily switch between them (I have Swedish, English and French keyboards).

Comment: Just an FYI, `\`` backticks are meant for formatting inline code samples, console commands and such. Please don't use them for general-purpose highlighting. If you want to highlight certain words or terms, use bold or italics. For menu options, quotation marks also work well. Thanks!

Comment: @Indrek http://meta.windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/254/how-to-highlight-something